# GoogleApiClient - Connected / Selected User Account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

How do I get the actual connected / selected user from the GoogleApiClient?

I use this code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
```

The user selects the account from the popup and "onConnected" is called, but I don't get the account which was selected.

I want to display this information, so how can I get this info?

Answer (score -1):

```
      private void getProfileInformation() {
           try {
          if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

          }

    catch(Exception e){}


  }

    }
```

On OnConnected Call getProfileInformation Method

```
  @Override
   public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get user's information
    getProfileInformation();



}
```

Comment: Yeah I have seen this method, but do I really need the PLUS PeopleApi to get this information? It is a little bit overhead for this... The user selects it already, so very strange that I don't get it directly from googleApiClient.

Comment: Yes You Will Need To Call Plus Api To Get All This Info

Comment: Very strange. OK,but getCurrentPerson is deprecated.

Comment: I made user to select the account to user in a app and then  use that account for plus login

Comment: And what if the user does not have a Plus account? I only need the mail address of the selected user in the Drive API account chooser...

Comment: Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    }
}